# Comparison one entity with other #tweeter data

Tags: python, nltk, text-analysis

I am exploring NLTK and other text analysis as i am a aspiring student in data analytics.
I am breaking my head to figure out how this can be done in Text analysis
Question 1)I have crawled tweeter data of #entity1 and #entity2
I want to compare what issues or how people are comparing entity 1 with entity 2
ex: i ate in #entity1 their service was good but not as good as we get in #entity 2(something on this lines). 
I have tried some tweeter data from kaggle to do sentiment analysis and stuff. But when this scenario comes i am stuck as to how to move ahead. 
Any starting suggestions are welcome.